# How do you beat the fourth room of the Portal: The Flash Version map pack?

Tags: portal

I seem to be having trouble in the fourth room of the Portal The Flash Version Map Pack.  It's kind of irritating because, well, *it's just the fourth room*!  This one should be child's play!

The second part of the fourth room in the map pack seems as if it's meant to be analogous to room 6 in the flash game, but the same trick doesn't quite appear to work here.  Any hints/tips?

Comment: I don't really know which room you're talking about, they aren't numbered.

Comment: @RavenDreamer As far as I can tell, this question is about the [Flash Version Map Pack](http://portalmaps.wecreatestuff.com/), which is actually a custom campaign for Portal, *based* on the Flash version made by the same people.

Comment: @lunboks I'm counting rooms as they are separated by actual doors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've counted correctly, this is a walkthrough of room 4 (and beyond):

It appears to be a couple of those `"speedy thing goes in, speedy thing comes out"` puzzles. This means you'll need to use your falling momentum to shoot you out of a wall, over a jump. Also notice that, in this video, the player crouches as they are flying through the air, presumably to make Chell more compact and therefore more likely to make the jumps.

Comment: For all you Portal lovers out there, I highly recommend this map pack, since it's all new content and almost as long as the original game. [Download link](http://portalmaps.wecreatestuff.com/)

Comment: especially if one has played [the flash version](http://portal.wecreatestuff.com/) before

Comment: It appears you indeed have counted correctly.  The solution looks similar to something I'm sure I've already tried, but I'll give it another shot.  Thanks.

Comment: Ah, it seems crouching was indeed the key.  Thanks again!